# Method pointer template doesn't compile

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

The following C++ code does not compile in MS Visual Studio 2010:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    /// Provides the signature of the methods that can be given to addValueSetListener
    template <typename TT>
    struct ChangeHandler
    {
        typedef void ( TT::* OnSetValueMethod )();
    };

    template <typename TT>
    void bar_ok(TT*, void ( TT::* )(), bool = false) {}
    template <typename TT>
    void bar_ok(const char*, TT*, void ( TT::* )()) {}

    template <typename TT>
    void bar_fails(TT*, typename ChangeHandler<TT>::OnSetValueMethod, bool = false) {}
    template <typename TT>
    void bar_fails(const char*, TT*, typename ChangeHandler<TT>::OnSetValueMethod) {}

    void testBar() {}
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo; 
  foo.bar_ok   ("allo",& foo, & Foo::testBar);  // compiles
  foo.bar_fails("allo",& foo, & Foo::testBar);  // compile ERROR
}
```

The compiler error is `'TT': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'`, for the ERROR line.

The only difference between the line that fails and the one that doesn't is that bar_fails declares the  "method pointer type" argument `void (TT::*)()` via a "templated typedef", whereas bar_ok declares it directly.

Note that without the overload for `const char*`, the templated typedef works fine. With the const char* overload available, the compiler erroneously chooses the `TT=[const char]` overload of bar_fails yet it correctly chooses the TT=Foo overload of bar_ok. This issue does not arise when the typedef is for a "simple" data like TT* or float*.

Comment: There is no way the line you've marked as `// compiles` does.  All those members are `private` for a start.  Can you please show us the real code.

Comment: And `main` return an `int` too... (it seems it is a typo)

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud yes sorry I fixed this

Comment: @PaulEvans good eye a typo when I pasted in multiple pieces the public: went missing, edited to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in the `bar_ok` case, [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE) can apply, as the erroneous construct `const char::*` appears in direct context of template parameter substitution. In the `bar_fail` case, it's one step removed (hidden in the "template typedef"), which means SFINAE no longer applies and the compiler must process the syntactic nonsense of `const char::*`, thus halting and reporting the error.

In other words, it's not that the compiler chooses the wrong overload in `bar_fail`. It has to examine both overloads in both cases, but in the first one is it allowed to disregard the erroneous one by SFINAE, while in the second one it's "too late."

Comment: I hadn't noticed the subtlety of "direct context", but after further tests based on this answer, that is indeed the issue. The work-around is in the next answer because I can't fit it in a comment. I'm leaving Angew's answer as accepted answer because without it, I wouldn't have known where to look. Thanks Angew!

Answer (score 1):

Angew provided a simple explanation of why the code in my OP doesn't work. So is there a workaround? Turns out it is really simple, but the explanation doesn't fit in a comment, so here it is.

As pointed out by Angew, SFINAE only applies at the direct substitution level, so this compiles:

```
template <typename TT> void testFunc(TT) {}
template <typename TT> void testFunc(typename TT::Foo) {}
int main()
{
    testFunc<int>(3);
}
```

Indeed the compiler knows to drop the second overload of `testFunc`: an integer doesn't have a nested `Foo` type. If SFINAE weren't available at all in C++, this would halt compilation.

Now if you change the above implementation slightly to use a traits-like class, the following completely equivalent code no longer compiles:

```
template <typename TT>
struct Helper
{
    typedef typename TT::Foo MyFoo;
};
template <typename TT> void testFunc(TT) {}
template <typename TT> void testFunc(typename Helper<TT>::MyFoo) {}

int main()
{
    testFunc<int>(3);
}
```

because the compiler is "inside" the `Helper<int>` class when it is resolving the MyFoo typedef; it balks at the `int::Foo`, direct SFINAE does not apply, so it gives up compilation.

You might notice that in my OP, I didn't specify the template parameter explicitly, whereas in the above, I do: that's because the compiler knows param is an int so it matches all `testFunc` that take `int` as parameter, it doesn't try all `testFunc<int>`. In my OP, I didn't need to specify the template parameter explicitly to get the error, because the first function argument did this for me. Let's do away with the method pointer because it clouds the problem, my original problem is exhibited by the following simpler code where I don't explicitly specify the template parameter:

```
struct Foo
{
    template <typename TT> struct Helper
    {
        typedef typename TT::Foo MyFoo;
    };

    template <typename TT> void bar(TT*, typename Helper<TT>::MyFoo) {}
    template <typename TT> void bar(const char*, TT*) {}
};


int main()
{
    Foo foo; 
    foo.bar("allo", & foo);  // ok
}
```

The compiler sees the first function call parameter to `foo.bar` as a `const char*`, so it knows it has to consider both `bar(const char*, Foo*)` and `bar(const char*, Helper<const char>::MyFoo)`. Then inside `Helper<const char>` it tries to resolve `const char::Foo` and halts compilation (again direct SFINAE does not apply).

One solution is to drop the `Helper` and stick to direct nested type:

```
struct Foo
{
    template <typename TT> void bar(TT*, typename TT::Foo) {}
    template <typename TT> void bar(const char*, TT*) {}
};
```

However this is not ideal for me because in my actual code my `bar()` is expecting a method pointer and I'm trying to make this clear in the declaration (though I'm wondering now if the templated typedef helps or hinders, but that's another matter).

The second solution is to use SFINAE to make compiler balk at the `bar` level. Turns out this is easy to do: define a specialization of `Helper` for `const char` that is missing parts:

```
struct Foo
{
    template <typename TT> struct Helper
    {
        typedef typename TT::Foo MyFoo;
    };
    template <> struct Helper<const char>
    {
    };

    template <typename TT> void bar(TT*, typename Helper<TT>::MyFoo) {}
    template <typename TT> void bar(const char*, TT*) {}
};
```

Now when the compiler matches `TT` to `const char`, it has two overloads to consider:

```
void bar(const char*, Helper<const char>::MyFoo)
void bar(const char*, Foo*)
```

But `Helper<const char>::MyFoo` doesn't exist in the specialization, so SFINAE can be used: the compiler hasn't had to go "inside" `Helper<T>`.

Those 3 lines for specialization were sufficient to solve the problem.